# CSS :before content value changing until cache is cleared

Tags: html, css, encoding, character-encoding

I have a ul list with chevron bullet points effected by the following css code:

```
ul li::before { 
content : "»"; 
padding-right: 0.3em;
}
```

This displays correctly initially; however after a while the bullet points change to Â». This is fixed (for a while) by clearing the cache, but the problem will then recur, and I can't for the life of me work out why the extra character is appearing. I have tried content: "\»" and content: "\00bb", but the same problem happens.
This happens in Chrome and I *think* also Safari, in my local development environment as well as on the live website  (http://markfisher.photo - the list in question is at the bottom under "Me elsewhere").

**Further Info (Quite confusing, but if you follow you may be able to force the problem to manifest itself in Chrome):**

Interestingly, looking at my live website now, even though it displays correctly on the page, upon inspecting the list, Chrome devtools says that the css is actually content: "\Â»". Refreshing the page with devtools open changes this, so it is then correct both on the page and in Chrome devtools. However, if I open the page (displaying correctly), open Chrome devtools (showing the extra Â) then close devtools and THEN refresh, the extra Â displays on the page.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://markfisher.photo/code/css/footer.css, when called directly in the browser, shows it that way already:

```
div.quick_links ul li::before { 
   content : "\Â»";
```

Switching the encoding explicitly to UTF-8 in the browser however makes it become `"\»"` then.

Try specifically telling the browser that this stylesheet is encoded in UTF-8, either by making the server add a `charset` to the `Content-Type` header, so that it becomes

```
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
```

or by placing the line

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

at the very beginning of your stylesheet.